# C code : Check whether alphanumeric value falls in specific alphanumeric range

Tags: c, validation, sequence, alphanumeric

How can I check with a C code,
whether a given string falls within the start and stop range of alphanumeric values?

```
Eg : 
given_string = "G32"
start_string = "F00"
stop_string  = "H44"

The valid sequence here will be a set of values below:
F00 F01 F02 ------ F99
G00 G01 G02 G03 ----- G99
H00 H01 H02 H03 ----- H44
```

So in this case G32 falls in the range F00 - H44. Hence G32 will be valid.
If we consider E99 or H45, they will not fall in the range. Hence they will be invalid.

Comment: Should "H5" fall into the range? Alphabetically it does not; numerically it does. What I am trying to illustrate is that you need to be more precise about sorting concept and/or assumptions on input syntax (e.g. length of string to check).

Comment: IMO OP makes it clear with "The **valid sequence** will be the set of values below:". "H5" is not valid.

Comment: That's right Yano.
These validations are done much before validating the given_string for the range.
The letter part is validated separately and the 2 digit number part is validated separately.

Other examples of  invalid input strings:
1E5
6NZ
A1
1A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char letter;
    int number;
} value_t;

value_t get_value(char *str)
{
    value_t result;

    if (strlen(str) != 3  ||    // Validate that string is 3 characters long
            !isupper(*str)  ||  // Validate that first character is uppercase
            !isdigit(str[1]  ||  !isdigit(str[2])) {  // Validate that remaining characters are digits
        printf("Invalid string!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    result.letter = *str;
    result.number = (str[1] - '0') * 10 + (str[2] - '0');
    return result;
}

int in_range(value_t min,value_t max,value_t val)
{
    if (val.letter < min.letter  ||  (val.letter == min.letter  &&  val.number < min.number))
        return 0;
    if (val.letter > max.letter  ||  (val.letter == max.letter  &&  val.number > max.number))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    value_t MIN = { 'F', 0 }, MAX = { 'H', 44 }, val;

    val = get_value(argv[1]);
    if (in_range(MIN,MAX,val))
        printf("%s is in range\n",argv[1]);
    else
        printf("%s is out of range\n",argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcmp`.  From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

```
strcmp() returns an integer indicating the result of the comparison, as follows:
• 0, if the s1 and s2 are equal;
• a negative value if s1 is less than s2;
• a positive value if s1 is greater than s2.
```

here is some illustrative code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool StrInRange(const char* start, const char* end, const char* testStr)
{
    // start is "F00", so if this comparison returns 0 or negative,
    // testStr is equal or "bigger" than testStr
    bool aboveStart = strcmp(start, testStr) <= 0;
    // end is "H44", so if this comparison returns 0 or positive,
    // testStr is equal or "smaller" than testStr
    bool belowEnd = strcmp(end, testStr) >= 0;
    // if both are true, testStr is within range.
    return aboveStart && belowEnd;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char* START_STR = "F00";
    const char* END_STR = "H44";

    const char* testStrs[] = {"G32", "E99", "H45", "F00", "H44", "G00"};

    for (size_t i=0; i< sizeof(testStrs)/sizeof(*testStrs); i++)
    {
        if (StrInRange(START_STR, END_STR, testStrs[i]) == true)
        {
            printf("String in range\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("String NOT in range\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String in range
String NOT in range
String NOT in range
String in range
String in range
String in range
```

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/76z64rqne)

Things could change depending on string length, case, etc.

Comment: It's a shame I forgot about positive and negative return values of strcmp. I was trying such complicated ways like generating a sequence in between the range and matching the value - which is extremely not memory efficient.

Thank you Yano for a precise answer and also link to Demo. 

I learnt something from your way of answering too. Putting a Demonstration link :-)     
Thank you for that as well.

Comment: This would validate `FXY` and `G()` and `H4`

Comment: @SGeorgiades none of those are in the **valid set** described by OP.

Comment: @yano Yes... and therefore should be rejected as invalid. We should promote proper error checking.

Comment: @SGeorgiades OP has indicated in the comments that type of validation is already occurring prior to reaching this point of the code, so it is outside the scope of the question. It's quite apparent by the time this part of the code is reached, the OP will have some 3 char string starting with a capital letter followed by 2 numbers. That being said, in no way am I insisting my answer is the _only_ or _best_ way to solve the problem. But it is a viable solution given the problem constraints and requirements.